# Writing a circuit in ZoKrates to proof age is over 21 years

Tags: ethereum, solidity, proof

I am trying to see if I can use ZoKrates in a scenario where a user can prove to the verifier that age is over 21 years without revealing the date of birth. I think its a good use case for zero-knowledge proof but like to understand the best way to implement it.

The circuit code (sample) takes the name of the user as public input(name attestation is done by a trusted authority like DMV and is a most likely combination of offline/online mechanism), then the date of birth which is a private input.

```
//8297122105 = "Razi" is decimal.
def main(pubName,private yearOfBirth, private centuryOfBirth):
  x = 0
  y = 0
  z = 0
  x = if centuryOfBirth == 19 then 1 else 0 fi
  y = if yearOfBirth < 98 then 1 else 0 fi
  z = if pubName == 8297122105 then 1 else 0 fi
  total =  x + y + z 
  result = if total == 3 then 1 else 0 fi

  return result
```

Now, using  `./target/release/zokrates generate-proof`  command get the output that can be used as an input to`verifier.sol`.

```
A = Pairing.G1Point(0x24cdd31f8e07e854e859aa92c6e7f761bab31b4a871054a82dc01c143bc424d, 0x1eaed5314007d283486826e9e6b369b0f1218d7930cced0dd0e735d3702877ac);
A_p = Pairing.G1Point(0x1d5c046b83c204766f7d7343c76aa882309e6663b0563e43b622d0509ac8e96e, 0x180834d1ec2cd88613384076e953cfd88448920eb9a965ba9ca2a5ec90713dbc);
B = Pairing.G2Point([0x1b51d6b5c411ec0306580277720a9c02aafc9197edbceea5de1079283f6b09dc, 0x294757db1d0614aae0e857df2af60a252aa7b2c6f50b1d0a651c28c4da4a618e], [0x218241f97a8ff1f6f90698ad0a4d11d68956a19410e7d64d4ff8362aa6506bd4, 0x2ddd84d44c16d893800ab5cc05a8d636b84cf9d59499023c6002316851ea5bae]);
B_p = Pairing.G1Point(0x7647a9bf2b6b2fe40f6f0c0670cdb82dc0f42ab6b94fd8a89cf71f6220ce34a, 0x15c5e69bafe69b4a4b50be9adb2d72d23d1aa747d81f4f7835479f79e25dc31c);
C = Pairing.G1Point(0x2dc212a0e81658a83137a1c73ac56d94cb003d05fd63ae8fc4c63c4a369f411c, 0x26dca803604ccc9e24a1af3f9525575e4cc7fbbc3af1697acfc82b534f695a58);
C_p = Pairing.G1Point(0x7eb9c5a93b528559c9b98b1a91724462d07ca5fadbef4a48a36b56affa6489e, 0x1c4e24d15c3e2152284a2042e06cbbff91d3abc71ad82a38b8f3324e7e31f00);
H = Pairing.G1Point(0x1dbeb10800f01c2ad849b3eeb4ee3a69113bc8988130827f1f5c7cf5316960c5, 0xc935d173d13a253478b0a5d7b5e232abc787a4a66a72439cd80c2041c7d18e8);
K = Pairing.G1Point(0x28a0c6fff79ce221fccd5b9a5be9af7d82398efa779692297de974513d2b6ed1, 0x15b807eedf551b366a5a63aad5ab6f2ec47b2e26c4210fe67687f26dbcc7434d);
```

**Question**

Consider a scenario when a user (say Razi) can take the proof above (probably in a form of a QR code) and scan it on a machine (confirms age is over 21) that will run the verifierTx method on the contract. Since the proof explicitly has "Razi" inside the proof and contract can verify the age without knowing the actual date of birth we get a better privacy. However, the challenge is now anyone else can reuse the proof since it was used within the transaction. One way to mitigate this issue is to make sure that either the proof is valid for a limited time or (just may good for one-time use). Another way is to ensure proof of user's identity ("Razi"), in a way that is satisfied beyond doubt (e.g. by confirming identity on blockchain etc.).

Are there ways to make sure proof can be used by a user more than once?

I hope the question and explanation make sense. Happy to elaborate more on this, so let me know.

Comment: Please note that you don’t actually have a question in the question section, only statements. What is the question?

Comment: Added additional details.

Answer (score 1):

What you will need is:

- Razi owning an ethereum public/private key
- a (salted) fingerprint fact (e.g. birthday as unix timestamp) associated with Razi's public ethereum address and endorsed on-chain by an authority

Now you can write a ZoKrates program like this

```
def main(private field salt, private field birthdayAsUnixTs, field pubFactHashA, field pubFactHashB, field ts) -> (field)
    // check that the fact is corresponding to the endorsed salted fact fingerprint onchain
    h0, h1 = sha256packed(0,0,salt,birthdayAsUnixTs)
    h0 == pubFactHashA
    h1 == pubFactHashB

    // 18 years is pseudo code only!
    field ok = if birthdayAsUnixTs * 18 years <= ts then 1 else 0 fi

    return ok
```

Now in your contract you can

- check that msg.sender is the owner of the endorsed fact
- require(ts <= now)
- call verifier with the proof and public input: (factHash, ts, 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by hashing the proof and adding that hash in a list of "used proofs", so no one can use it again.

Now, ZoKrates add randomness in the generation of the proof in order to prevent revealing that the same witnesss has been used, since zkproofs do not show anything about the witness. So, if you want to prevent the person to use his credential (accredit that he is over 21 years old ) more than once you have to use a nullifier (See [ZCash](https://z.cash/technology/zksnarks/) approach in the "How zk-SNARKs are applied to create a shielded transaction" part).

Basically you use a string with the data of Razi `nullifier_string = centuryOfBirth+yearOfBirth+pubName` and then you publish it Hash `nullifier = H(nullifier_string)` in a table of revealed nullifiers. In the ZoKrates scheme you have to add the nullifier as a public input and then verify that the nullifier corresponds to the data provided. Something like this:

```
import "utils/pack/unpack128.code" as unpack
import "hashes/sha256/256bitPadded.code" as hash
import "utils/pack/nonStrictUnpack256.code" as unpack256

def main(pubName,private yearOfBirth, private centuryOfBirth, [2]field nullifier):

  field x = if centuryOfBirth == 19 then 1 else 0 fi
  field y = if yearOfBirth < 98 then 1 else 0 fi
  field z = if pubName == 8297122105 then 1 else 0 fi
  total =  x + y + z 
  result = if total == 3 then 1 else 0 fi

  null0 = unpack(nullifier[0])
  null1 = unpack(nullifier[1])
  nullbits = [...null0,...null1]

  nullString = centuryOfBirth+yearOfBirth+pubName
  unpackNullString = unpack256(nullString)

  nullbits == hash(unpackNullString)


  return result
```

This has to be made in order to prevent that Razi provide a random nullifier unrelated to his data.

Once you had done this, you can check if the nullifier provided has been already used if it is registered in the revealed nullifier table.

The problem with this in your case is that the year of birth is a weak number to hash. Someone can do a brute-force attack to the nullifier and reveal the year of birth of Razi. You have to add a strong number in the verification (Razi secret ID? a digital signature?) to prevent this attack.

Note1: I have an old version of ZoKrates, so check the import path right.

Note2: Check the ZoKrates Hash function implementation, you may have problem with the padding of the inputs, the unpack256 function prevent this I suppose, but you can double check this to prevent bugs.